# Adding menu(overflow) to the customize title bar in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a customize title bar in my activity.

Now I want to add menu (overflow) as shown in the below figure to my customize title bar.

[image]

I refer to this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/) . But, it's not working for me some how. I just want overflow menu with 3 items in it.

Here is my code.

Activity.java

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menutit, menu);

            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }
```

MenuTit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <!-- Search / will display always -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/yellow"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="action_search"/>

    <!-- Location Found -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_location_found"
        android:icon="@drawable/yellow"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="action_location_found"/>

    <!-- More -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/a_More"
        android:icon="@drawable/yellow"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="More">
        <menu>

            <!-- Refresh -->
            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
                android:icon="@drawable/brown"
                android:showAsAction="never"
                android:title="action_refresh"/>

            <!-- Help -->
            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_help"
                android:icon="@drawable/brown"
                android:showAsAction="never"
                android:title="action_help"/>

            <!-- Check updates -->
            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_check_updates"
                android:icon="@drawable/brown"
                android:showAsAction="never"
                android:title="action_check_updates"/>
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Can any body tell is there something special I need to do for adding a menu items to the customize title bar ?

Comment: Which part isn't working... were you able to make the other (non-overflow) action items appear in the actionBar?

Comment: Do you use `appcompat` or `sherlockactionbar`?

Comment: @Fllo No I have not use appcompat or sherlockactionbar.

Comment: @es0329 I just want menu and it's not working I have not uses action bar I just want menu so i guess I don't need action bar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the items in your menu xml, and use showAsAction = never or ifRoom.

Comment: I did that still it is not working. It's not giving me any error but it is not displaying menu.

Comment: What if you press the menu button? Is there an options menu coming up with the rest of the missing items?

Comment: Added code to original post. Menu button is not showing at all.

Comment: I mean the harware menu button of the device

Comment: Ya it displaying Settings at the bottom of the Activity.

Comment: Your problem is that Android is designed in a way to use the overflow item in the actionbar for devices not having a phisycal menu button. If you remove the "More" menu item from around the Refresh, Help, etc., they will appear in the options menu. You should do it that way, except of corse if you have a really pushing client, who really wants to have the overflow item in the action bar in all devices.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49108/discussion-between-eswaat-and-ripityom)